# kubectl ImagePullBackOff due to secret

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm creating kubevirt in minikube, initially kubevirt-operator.yaml fails with ImagePullBackOff. After I added secret in the yaml

```
imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
containers:
```

all my virt-operator* started to run. virt-api* pods still shows ImagePullBackOff.
The error comes out as

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  27m                    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kubevirt/virt-api-787487d9cd-t68qf to minikube
  Normal   Pulling    25m (x4 over 27m)      kubelet            Pulling image "us-ashburn-1.ocir.io/xxx/virt-api:v0.54.0"
  Warning  Failed     25m (x4 over 27m)      kubelet            Failed to pull image "us-ashburn-1.ocir.io/xxx/virt-api:v0.54.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for us-ashburn-1.ocir.io/xxx/virt-api, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Anonymous users are only allowed read access on public repos
  Warning  Failed     25m (x4 over 27m)      kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     25m (x6 over 27m)      kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    2m26s (x106 over 27m)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "us-ashburn-1.ocir.io/xxx/virt-api:v0.54.0"
```

**Manually, I can pull the same image with docker login.** Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the output iof `kubectl get secret regcred`

Comment: kubectl get secret regcred -n kubevirt
NAME      TYPE                             DATA   AGE
regcred   kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson   1      10h

Comment: In which namespace are you creating the pod? I assume it's `kubevirt`?

Answer (score 1):

This docker image looks like it is in a private registry(and from oracle). And I assume the regcred is not correct. Can you login there with docker login? if so you can create regcred secret like this

```
$ kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<region-key>.ocir.io --docker-username='<tenancy-namespace>/<oci-username>' --docker-password='<oci-auth-token>' --docker-email='<email-address>'
```

Also check this oracle tutorial: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/oci/oke-and-registry/index.html

Comment: I'm sure that regcred is correct, reason other images in the same registry is working fine.
`
kubectl get pod -n kubevirt
NAME                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
virt-api-787487d9cd-t68qf        0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          10h
virt-api-787487d9cd-wr8tc        0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          10h
virt-operator-859879d968-4td8b   1/1     Running            0          10h
virt-operator-859879d968-ghlm8   1/1     Running            0          10h
`

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find  the [steps to implement secret values to the cluster](https://www.containiq.com/post/kubernetes-secrets).

If you are using a private registry, check that your [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) exists and the secret is correct. Your secret should also be in the same namespace.

Your Minikube is a VM not your localhost. You try this

1. Open Terminal
2. eval $(minikube docker-env)
3. docker build .
4. kubectl create -f deployment.yaml

just valid this terminal. if closed terminal again open terminal and write eval $(minikube docker-env)

eval $(minikube docker-env) this code build image in Minikube

Also, try to login docker on all nodes by using [docker login](https://hub.docker.com).

There is also a lengthy blog post describing how to debug image pull back-off in depth  [here](https://managedkube.com/kubernetes/k8sbot/troubleshooting/imagepullbackoff/2019/02/23/imagepullbackoff.html)

Comment: Yes "imagePullSecrets" is in the level of spec as described in the link

Comment: My doubt is secret has to be configured somewhere or in some yaml file execution. Seems kubectl/kubevirt has to be explicitly provided with the secret.

Comment: Secret should be configured in the yaml file, secrets are to be mounted by the user kubectls does not provide any secrets.

Comment: "Your secret should also be in the same namespace." -- this was it for me. THANKS!

Answer (score -1):

Hey if you look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/). I think you can find some helpful documentation.
What they are doing is, they are upload the dockerconfig file which has login credentials as a secret and then referring to that in the deployment.
You could try to follow these steps and do something similar. Let me know if it works